# Create a SharePoint 2019 Application Server and join an existing Farm?

Tags: sharepoint-server, 2019, minrole, application-server, windows-server-2019

What is the best practice to create a SharePoint 2019 Application Server and join an existing Farm?

2x Application Minrole Servers require a rebuild due to a corruption within the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an article from Microsoft: [Add a server to a SharePoint Servers 2016 or 2019 farm](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/install/add-a-server-to-a-sharepoint-server-2016-farm). Just follow the steps in this article. Note that you need to specify server role as application Server in SharePoint configuration wizard.